# Can't send a message via custom store/dispatch in botframework-webchat for IE11/es5

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, internet-explorer-11, es5-compatiblity

My customer requires IE11 support for our chatbot. I had to modify the webchat code not to use es6 features like arrow functions, as they are not supported in IE11/es5. For the most part I was successful, but the one thing I wasn't able to get working was sending a message event I am sending. The new code works in Chrome, but I am getting an ***Expected identifier*** error message in IE11. Here is the relevant code:

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, function({dispatch}) { return function(next) { return function(action) {
    if (action.type === 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE') {
        // Message sent by the user
        PageTitleNotification.Off();
        clearTimeout(interval);
    } else if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY' && action.payload.activity.name !== "inactive") {
        // Message sent by the bot
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setTimeout(function() {
            // Change title to flash the page
            PageTitleNotification.On('Are you still there?');

            // Notify bot the user has been inactive
            dispatch({
                type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                payload: {
                    name: 'inactive',
                    value: ''
                }
            });

        }, 3000)
    }
    return next(action);
}}});
```

Previously the first line looked like

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
```

The issue is coming at `function({dispatch})`. IE console is saying an identifier is expected and the entire webchat fails to load. It works fine in Chrome. If I change `function({dispatch})` to just `function(dispatch)`, the bot renders but the dispatch statement sending the inactive message to the bot (below) no longer functions in IE *OR* Chrome.

```js
// Notify bot the user has been inactive
dispatch({
    type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
    payload: {
        name: 'inactive',
        value: ''
    }
});
```

Why is IE not recognizing `{dispatch}` as an identifier, and what can I do to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE11 doesn't support that syntax. ES6 allows to set object properties by variable name, so the ES5 equivalent is:

```
window.WebChat.createStore({}, { dispatch: dispatch }) {
  // ...
}
```

Edit:

After some debugging, the final solution was to pass in just the `dispatch` object to the `createStore` function directly, and accessing its `dispatch` method:

```
dispatch.dispatch({
    type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
    payload: {
        name: 'inactive',
        value: ''
    }
});
```

You could rename the argument to reduce redundancy but it's not needed.

Comment: Perfect! Now that I see your answer, I ran into this in the `renderWebChat` call as well (changed `adaptiveCardsHostConfig` to `adaptiveCardsHostConfig: adaptiveCardsHostConfig`) but it didn't occur to me that this problem could be solved the same way. Thanks!

Comment: Ugh, sorry to do this but I accidentally checked in Edge instead of IE11. I'm still getting the same error in IE11, expected identifier and pointing to dispatch in the line `const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, function({dispatch:dispatch}) { return function(next) { return function(action) { ...`

Comment: Oh I tried without function (just `{dispatch:dispatch}` but it didn't like that either.

Comment: Can you set each argument to its own line to see if we can determine which part of that line is causing the issue? Passing an object to a function argument shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Before it was just a chain of arrow functions. I'm not sure how else to change the syntax to break that chain apart.

Comment: So it's just one argument with 3 nested functions. What the first function wants is `function({dispatch})` (or I believe `function({dispatch: dispatch})` works too), but IE11 won't accept this. That is definitely what is causing the issue. If I change to `function(dispatch)` the webchat will actually render, however I then get *dispatch is not a function* in the console when it tries to sent the `inactive` event.

Comment: I should note that dispatch is NOT something I have defined elsewhere in the code. I'm guessing this is part of the problem and something IE can't handle. It only appears in the function definition `function({dispatch}) {` and in the call to send the message a little further down.

Comment: What about changing it to `function(dispatch)` and changing the dispatch call to `dispatch.dispatch({ type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT' ..})`. I don't see why IE would not like the proposed solution, another way you can go about this is running it through an automatic transpiler to target ES5.

Comment: That was it! Sticking with `dispatch` as the function argument and changing the call to `dispatch.dispatch` did the trick! I've reaccepted the answer but it would be a good idea to add this to the solution for others.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't check in Edge? ;)  Glad it's working now Bill.

Comment: @billoverton, the problem is you never call `return next(action)` in your store (see my posted solution). This is what advances the flow.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your posted code is you never `return next(action)`. Therefore the flow never advances when it runs thru the `store`. Add this one line and web chat will work as expected sending every 3 seconds. You can reference the code in the [05.custom-components/b.send-typing-indicator](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/05.custom-components/b.send-typing-indicator#completed-code) Web Chat sample, if needed.

Please note:

- I commented out `PageTitleNotification` as it's undefined.
- I did had to define `interval` which you must define elsewhere in your code not provided.
- Be sure you are using the `webchat-es5.js` CDN which is backed with polyfills for running on IE.

Hope of help!

```js
var interval;
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, function(dispatch) {
  return function(next) {
    return function(action) {
      console.log(action)
      if (action.type === 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE') {
          // Message sent by the user
          // PageTitleNotification.Off();
          clearTimeout(interval);
      } else
      if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
          // Message sent by the bot
          clearInterval(interval);
          interval = setTimeout(function() {
              // Change title to flash the page
              // PageTitleNotification.On('Are you still there?');

              // Notify bot the user has been inactive
              dispatch.dispatch({
                  type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                  payload: {
                      name: 'inactive',
                      value: ''
                  }
              });

          }, 3000)
      }
      return next( action )
    }
  }
} );
```

**Developer console:**

[image]

**Bot logging:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the additional help. I do have `return next(action)` immediately following the code snippet I pasted. Accidentally left it out. I also have PageTitleNotification and interval defined elsewhere as well and was using webchat-es5.js for IE11 compatibility. This answer provides good context for others who don't have the benefit of seeing my full code. I will say though that the issue was in the `function({dispatch})` line (only with IE11). I had to use `function(dispatch)` and use dispatch as `dispatch.dispatch(myActivity)` instead of `dispatch(myActivity)`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll edit my post to show that. I made that same change, but had already copied your code for the post. I edited that and forgot to change. Glad it's working for you.